# React app works locally but not when served from django server

Tags: django, reactjs, frontend, backend

I'm new to React development but I've done some courses on it and I get how it generally works.

At the moment I'm just trying to figure out how to connect a React front end to a Django backend. Literally, just have Django serve the React page.

I've built a simple React app that works when I run it locally (just open up the templates/index.html). But When I try to run it via Django's development server, it doesn't work.

I'm using babelify and babel-preset-react (which I'm also new to).

I'm having my main.jsx file compile to a main.js file that I link to in my index.html page.

When checking chrome's console, I've slightly narrowed down the problem:

On the local version (when I directly open the file in chrome), the resulting main.js file is indeed what you would expect, a large Javascript file that was generated after compiling main.jsx, and everything is fine.

But when I try to access the same index.html page through Django's server (manage.py runserver), that same main.js file that it links to does not contain JavaScript, it actually contains the same content as the index.html file itself.

I don't see how that's possible. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: If your .js file suddenly contains html instead of javascript, this is not a React question. It would be more your Django code in cause. You talk about the "local" version and the "django" version, but "manage.py runserver" is still local so it should use the same file. Apparently you made django refer to a different file. WIthout showing more code it won't be easy to debug.